# Using SQL STUFF to concatenate rows that I cannot group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to get a comma-delimited list of user roles for a specific app. I've used `STUFF` and `FOR XML PATH('')` for this problem before, but I don't know if I can in this situation. Here is the query that shows what I want to do, but doesn't work:

```
SELECT FName, LName, Email, Username, 
    STUFF((SELECT r.RoleDescription FROM Roles r2 WHERE r2.RoleID = r.RoleID FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') as RoleList
FROM Users u
INNER JOIN UserRole ur on u.UserID = ur.UserID
INNER JOIN Roles r on r.RoleID = ur.RoleID
WHERE ur.AppID = 506
GROUP BY FName, LName, Email, Username
```

This doesn't work because my where clause for the subquery contains a column that isn't in the `GROUP BY`. However if I group by the RoleID I lose the ability to combine those rows in the aggregate function.

Is there another way I can do this? Or a way that I could fix my query to achieve the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OUTER APPLY is far neater

```
SELECT FName, LName, Email, Username, 
    STUFF(x.csv,1,1,'') as RoleList
FROM Users u
INNER JOIN UserRole ur on u.UserID = ur.UserID
OUTER APPLY
    (
    SELECT
        ',' + r.RoleDescription
    FROM
        Roles r
    WHERE
        r.RoleID = ur.RoleID
    FOR XML PATH ('')
    ) x (csv)
WHERE ur.AppID = 506
GROUP BY FName, LName, Email, Username, x.csv
```

However, you may not need group by now because you don't repeat per joined `Role` row

```
SELECT FName, LName, Email, Username, 
    STUFF(x.csv,1,1,'') as RoleList
FROM Users u
INNER JOIN UserRole ur on u.UserID = ur.UserID
OUTER APPLY
    (
    SELECT
        ',' + r.RoleDescription
    FROM
        Roles r
    WHERE
        r.RoleID = ur.RoleID
    FOR XML PATH ('')
    ) x (csv)
WHERE ur.AppID = 506
```

For completeness, DISTINCT works better then GROUP BY for in-line sub queries because it is applied much later to the actual values. RoleId is not part of the actual values so won't break DISTINCT

Update for the filter which is actually on UserRole, which means we can use CROSS APPLY

```
SELECT FName, LName, Email, Username, 
    STUFF(x.csv,1,1,'') as RoleList
FROM Users u
CROSS APPLY
    (
    SELECT
        ',' + r.RoleDescription
    FROM
        UserRole ur
        JOIN
        Roles r ON ur.RoleID = r.RoleID
    WHERE
        u.UserID = ur.UserID
    FOR XML PATH ('')
    ) x (csv)
WHERE u.UserID IN (Select UserID FROM UserRole WHERE AppID = 506)
```

Comment: I'm still getting multiple rows for each person with each Role on a separate row. Doesn't appear that they are being grouped.

Comment: @joelforsyth: You have probably left `Roles` in with a JOIN. It is the *only* way you can get multiple rows like you described. `Roles` should only be in the APPLY sub-query

Comment: I ran both of your queries, unmodified, and got multiple rows per user. Note that the query returns the same number of results even without the outer apply: `SELECT FName, LName, Email, Username
FROM Users u 
INNER JOIN UserRole ur on u.UserID = ur.UserID
WHERE ur.AppID = 506` because UserRole is a N:N table

Comment: UserRole is of course N:N but where does AppID come into it then?

Comment: AppID is another column on UserRole. The table should be appropriately named, UserAppRole

Comment: This last update gives me the desired result, but returns the entire user base. I think I can figure it out from here. Thanks!